# fullcalendar highlight selected day

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I want to highlight only the `.fc-day-number` background if selected, not the whole day cell. But when i add CSS class into `.fc-highlight` the highlight background color doesn't work.

This is my sample css code:

```
.fc-highlight.fc-day-number { /* when user is selecting cells */
    background: #74c8d9;
    opacity: .3;
}
```

Then when i remove the `.fc-day-number` the highlight works fine.

I also have the same kind of css code using in `.fc-today` backgroud color.

The working sample the same css code:

```
.fc-today.fc-day-number {
    background-color: #fff2c5;
}
```

I combine these two classes and its working fine.

I dont know what is the problem that it doesnt work in highlight. Please help!

Comment: pls add example

Comment: which fullCalendar view(s) are we talking about?

Comment: You can make use of the fullcalendar "dayclick:" option, to add a certain class with your desired colours/actions.

eg:

dayClick: function (date) {

$(this).find(".yourclass").removeClass(yourClass)
$(this).addClass(yourclass);


}

This way you can first remove the class from other elements, and then add it to your clicked day.

Comment: @ADyson month view sir.